# How to say a particular author is the only one you've read every book of?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

Charles Dickens is an author. I have read every book he's written, and he's the only author who I can say this about.

If I wanted to express this fact, in **one single and elegant** sentence, what would be the best way to express this?

My best attempt:

> Charles Dickens is the only author whose every book I have read.

But this seems awkward and goofy to me. Is there a better way of stating this in one simple declarative sentence?

Comment: He’s the only author I’ve fully read...?

Comment: Among authors, there are some none of whose books I have read, and there are others some but not all of whose books I have read; and that leaves Charles Dickens. Said Bilbo.

Comment: You have consumed Dicken's canon.

Comment: @user662852 That sounds like the plot to a very disturbing porn film.

Comment: "Charles Dickens is the only author of whom I have read their entire published works." if you want to be a pretentious bookworm snob. :D

Comment: One has to wonder *why* you feel the need to say this.  (The reason would, to a degree, guide how the topic is discussed.)

Comment: *I've read every novel by Dickens.* Simple, clear, and unambiguous. *There's only one author whose every book I've read, and that is Dickens.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) has this entry for the noun *oeuvre*:

> **oeuvre** *n pl* **oeuvres** {F *œuvre*, lit., work, fr. OF *ovre*, L *opera* — more at OPERA} (1875) : a substantial body of work constituting the lifework of a writer, an artist, or a composer

Given this definition, you could say

> Charles Dickens is the only author whose entire oeuvre I have read.

Comment: @JEL: I almost omitted the _entire_ in my example because you can argue that _oeuvre_ covers everything in the person's body of work. I certainly wouldn't say "I have read most of his entire oeuvre." But idiomatically "entire ouevre" is sufficiently established (as [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=entire+oeuvre&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Centire%20oeuvre%3B%2Cc0) suggests) that it may qualify as an emphatic expression of completeness, and not merely a redundancy. I accept that opinions may vary on this point, however.

Comment: Or just *works*: "*C.D. is the only author whose complete works I have read.*" It is far more common to see "The Complete Works of W.S.*" than "*The Entire Oeuvre of W.S.*"

Comment: Charles Dickens is hors d'oeuvre to Shakespeare.

Answer (score 3):

> Charles Dickens is the only author all of whose works I have read.

Answer (score 0):

You might say:

> I've read every book of just one author, and that's Dickens.

You might write:

> I have read every book of but one author: Charles Dickens.

Answer (score 0):

Not really and answer, more of a related question:

Charles Dickens - I've read all his works.

OR, would you say...

Charles Dickens - I've read all his work.

Comment: Thank you Jasper. I had a mind to, but then I thought that sometimes another question can actually be an answer. Please allow me to call this a 'hybrid' answer. :)